# Swift: Present UIAlertController in closure

Tags: swift, closures, uialertcontroller

We are trying to present a `UIAlertController` from within a closure but get the error "Implicit use of self in closure, use self. to make capture semantics specific".  What exactly is the correct syntax here?

[image]

Comment: Do `self.showViewController(...)`. You need to explicitly call self when talking about your instance variables inside a block.

Comment: Thanks, got it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refer to "self" explicitly when talking about your object's instance variables inside a block.

`self.showViewController(...)`